# Build fails after using CocoaPods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am using CocoaPods for the first time. Installing required libraries causes the build process to break.

Installing Podfile gives this warning:

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Xcode 6.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)
```

The following is the build error message:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/aztunwin/ObjC/DenkoStation/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-RKValueTransformers/Pods-RKValueTransformers-dummy.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Update your project pods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error appears to be because you originally launched Xcode 6.1 from your disk image (`.dmg`) file, so that's where MacOS appears to be looking for the command line tools.  You need to reset that.

Go to terminal and type in:

```
xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Your copy of Xcode is really found in your /Applications folder (as I can see from the second error output).  Once you set the command line tools path using `xcode-select`, clean your project and restart Xcode and try building again.

Comment: I ran XCode from the dmg file for the first time. Maybe doing so set the path to the mounted volume. After following your suggestion, XCode seems to be working. Thanks.